# How properly abort a python coroutine in an infinite loop?

Tags: python, coroutine

My following code simulate UNIX pipes :

```
@coroutine
def grep(cible,motif):
    while True:
        line = yield
        if motif in line:
            cible.send("{}".format(line))

@coroutine
def subst(cible,old,new):
    while True:
        line = yield
        line=line.replace(old,new)
        cible.send("{}".format(line))

@coroutine
def lc(cible):
    nl = 0  
    while True:
            line = yield
            cible.send("{}".format(line))
    print(nl) # obvously not like that ! But how ??

@coroutine
def echo():
    while True:
        line = yield
        print(line)
```

For example :

```
pipe = grep(subst(lc(echo()),"old","new")," ")
for line in ["wathever","it's an old string","old_or_new","whitespaces for grep"]:
    pipe.send(line)
```

gives :

```
it's an new string
whitespaces for grep
```

lc must count the lines (like wc) and must return it at the end.
How can I do this ?

Comment: You need some way of indicating End-Of-File in your protocol; perhaps by sending a value of `None`.  Each of the stages in your pipeline would need to break out of their infinite loop when the EOF is received, and then send an EOF of its own to the next stage.

Comment: You can close coroutines. Have you tried closing the pipe and catching "GeneratorExit" from within lc to print your result?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know than a coroutine can be closed. So the solution of my problem is :

```
@coroutine
def lc(cible):
  nl = 0  
  while True:
      try:
        nl += 1  
        line = yield
      except GeneratorExit:
        cible.send("{}".format(nl))
        raise
```

and this needs in main :

```
pipe.close()
```

Thanks you very much RobertB !